# Wrap word in table cell

Tags: xetex, tabularx, wrap

I have such table:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |p{0.5cm}|X|p{1cm}|p{0.8cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{1.5cm}| }                                                                                                                  
    \hline                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    No. & Compound & Storage place & Shelf & Number & Calc mol & Cacl wt & Calc amount & Real mol & Real wt & Real amount \\                                                                                                                 
    \hline                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    1 & lasdsdasdasdasdasddasdllasfsdjfsd & Lab1 & 2 & 355235 & 85.000 & 92.006 & 1.33620 & 85.000 & 92.006 & 1.33620 g \\                                                                                                                   
    \hline                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
\end{tabularx}
```

How to wrap long word in second column? I would like to have table where text never ever overflow.

What I have now is:

[image]

What I would like to have:

[image]

Note: I'm using xelatex as compiler, I dont know if it makes difference.

Comment: First your table is too wide to fit in. Second, you may use `\hspace{0pt} lasdsdasdasdasdasddasdllasfsdjfsd` so that the long word is hyphenated. TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word. When you add `\hspace{0pt}`, you trick TeX to treat the long word as not the first word.

Comment: @HarishKumar - I doubt that there are any hyphenation rules that provide sensible guidance regarding the hyphenation of the remarkable string "lasdsdasdasdasdasddasdllasfsdjfsd"...

Comment: @Mico TeX hypheantes "lasdsdasdasdasdasddasdllasfsdjfsd" but, no rules followed ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar - great, works as intended. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Converting the comment into answer.</sub>

TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word. You can  add `\hspace{0pt}`, and  trick TeX to treat the long word as not the first word. Using `\hspace{0pt} lasdsdasdasdasdasddasdllasfsdjfsd` should do the job in the present case.

You may prefer to put it in the column definition itself like `>{\hspace{0pt}}X` thereby avoiding its specification in (each) cell.

Comment: `>{\hspace{0pt}}X` for the second column should avoid the need of specifying it explicitly in the cell.

Comment: Is there a solution when using something like `\begin{tabular}{l||r|r||r|r||r||r|r}`, i.e.: no fixed widths?