# Short word after long word in narrow table cell

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

In a narrow raggedright table cell with a long word followed by a short word (for example "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb"), if the first word is too wide and therefore hyphenated (using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198339/)), then the second word ends up in the third line even though it there's still enough space for it on the second line.

So instead of

```
aaaaaaaaaa-
aaaa bbb
```

I see

```
aaaaaaaaaa-
aaaa
bbb
```

This can be avoided by using a `~` between the two words, but can it be avoided automatically?

Small example with column type taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\title{tmp}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|L{50pt}|}
\hspace{0pt} Fooooo-ooo bar
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `ragged2e` package and its `\RaggedRight` command you can defne your `L` type column as shown in the following example.

In your original code, you used `tabularx` with a `p` type column of the same width. This causes an overfull box warning since the column will in fact be wider than the declared 50pt as 2*`\tabcolsep` (=2*6pt) will be added. `\tabcolsep` is the small hrizontal space between the vertical line and the start/end of the text. I have therefore added two alternative tables that do not produce this warning. The first alternative works entirely without `tabularx`, the second one uses a left aligned `X` type column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|L{50pt}|}
Fooooo-ooo bar 
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

Alternative without tabularx:

\begin{tabular}{|L{50pt}|}
Fooooo-ooo bar 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Alternative with tabularx's X type column:

\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}
Fooooo-ooo bar 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently `\let\newline\\ ` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/) is indeed unnecessary when using `ragged2e`.

Comment: Your solution works, but it hyphenates more rarely. i.e. it allows the long word to protrude extremely close to the vertical line without hyphenating the word, in cases where without `ragged2e` hyphenation occurs. Maybe the overfull hbox and the difference between the example and my big document are the reason.

Comment: Shouldn't https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/ be edited accordingly?

Comment: you changed the example text which completely changed the problem, the original problem is due to having a hyphen in the penultimate line of the paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Redefining the column type as in this answer does solve the *original* problem as well though.

Comment: @root yes because `\RaggedRight` only adds finite not infinite stretch so the cost of having three lines would be too high, but the code shown here doesn't show that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for pointing this out. I have changed the example text back to the original and corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

(beware the word space after `\hspace`)

The reason for the extra line is that TeX avoids having a hyphen on the last linebreak in a paragraph, it's only a mild hint but here with so little else happening the demerits from having  a hyphen there are enough to cause TeX to generate an extra line to avoid it. Normlly tex would have to over-stretch white space in order to get an extra line and the penalty from teh underfull lines would prevent this happening but here you have `\raggedright` which puts zero-penalty infinite stretch on every line, so the cost (as seen by TeX) of having a three line paragraph is rather low. If you set the hyphen demerits to 0 then it chooses a two line paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\title{tmp}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|L{50pt}|}
\finalhyphendemerits=0
\hspace{0pt}Fooooo-ooo bar

X\dotfill X
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since 2020, the `\raggedright` code contains `\finalhyphendemerits=0`, so a manual fix is not needed anymore.